# Создание Favorites листа Flutter

Tags: list, виджет, flutter, dart

Пытаясь создать некое приложение столкнулся с проблемой добавления айтемов из одного листа в лист избранного.
У меня есть некая функция которая генерирует лист с айтемами из `HoursData`,
Дата:

```dart
class HoursData {
  String name;
  String catergory;
  IconData iconData;
  String rt;

  HoursData({this.name, this.catergory, this.iconData, this.rt});
}

List<HoursData> data = [
    HoursData(name: 'Programming', catergory: 'Technology', iconData: Icons.computer, rt: '/programming'),
    HoursData(name: 'Run', catergory: 'Sport', iconData: Icons.directions_run, rt: '/run'),
    HoursData(name: 'Bike', catergory: 'Sport', iconData: Icons.directions_bike, rt: '/bike'),
  ];
```

И функция которая генерирует этот лист:

```dart
 List<Widget> _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return data.map((HoursData f) => ListTile(
              title: Text(f.name),
              subtitle: Text('Category: ${f.catergory}'),
              leading: Icon(f.iconData),
              trailing: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                 print('Tapped');
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.favorite_border,
                    ),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(f.rt),
            ))
        .toList();
  }
```

Класс с объявлением вкладок:

```dart
class _HoursListState extends State<HoursList> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('365 Hours'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
        body: _selectedIndex == 0
          ? Container(child: ListView(children: _buildList(context)))
          : (_selectedIndex == 1 
          ? Container(child: ListView(children: _pushFavorites(context))) 
          : Text('Settings')),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.list), title: Text('List')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), title: Text('Favorite')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Settings')),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на иконку `trailing`

1. Изменялось состояние иконки (Окрашивалась цветом)
2. Нужный айтем добавлялся в лист избранного со всеми параметрами кроме самой иконки в `trailing`, либо кнопкой удаления из списка избранного. Интересует его генерация. Избранное представлено вкладкой в боттомбаре.

## Генерация списка во вкладке Favorites

```dart
List<Widget> _pushFavorites(BuildContext context) {
    return favoriteData
        .map((HoursData f) => ListTile(
              title: Text(f.name),
              subtitle: Text('Category: ${f.catergory}'),
              leading: Icon(f.iconData),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(f.rt),
            ))
        .toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по простому то, так:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
    body: HomePage(),
  )));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: buildList(context),
    );
  }

  List<ListTile> buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return data
        .map((HoursData f) => ListTile(
              title: Text(f.name),
              subtitle: Text('Category: ${f.catergory}'),
              leading: Icon(f.iconData),
              trailing: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (f.favorite) {
                      favoriteData.remove(f);
                      f.favorite = false;

                      // Результат favoriteData
                      print('-----------');
                      favoriteData.forEach((element) => print(element.name));
                      print('-----------');
                    } else {
                      favoriteData.add(f);
                      f.favorite = true;

                      // Результат favoriteData
                      print('-----------');
                      favoriteData.forEach((element) => print(element.name));
                      print('-----------');
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.favorite_border,
                    color: (f.favorite) ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(f.rt),
            ))
        .toList();
  }
}

class HoursData {
  String name;
  String catergory;
  IconData iconData;
  String rt;
  bool favorite;

  HoursData({this.name, this.catergory, this.iconData, this.rt, this.favorite});
}

List<HoursData> data = [
  HoursData(
    name: 'Programming',
    catergory: 'Technology',
    iconData: Icons.computer,
    rt: '/programming',
    favorite: false,
  ),
  HoursData(
    name: 'Run',
    catergory: 'Sport',
    iconData: Icons.directions_run,
    rt: '/run',
    favorite: false,
  ),
  HoursData(
    name: 'Bike',
    catergory: 'Sport',
    iconData: Icons.directions_bike,
    rt: '/bike',
    favorite: false,
  ),
];

List<HoursData> favoriteData = new List<HoursData>();
```

Comment: Спасибо, выше написал функцию генерацию того самого листа.